# jQuery If myform.valid() is true then fire another jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a jQuery function that i would like to execute only if the form validation is true 
I have the validation and other jQuery working fine. 
the problem is now both validation and other function are executing same time.

I would like to run the other function only if the form validation is true.
here is my script

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.validator.addClassRules({
                    fileName: {
                        required: true
                    }
                });
                $("#myform").validate();
                if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                    $(function () {
                        $('#myform').submit(function () {
                            var cboxes = ($('input:checkbox:checked').filter(":checked").length);
                            var nboxes = ($(":checkbox:not(:checked)").length);
                            if ((cboxes > 0) && (nboxes > 0)) {
                                confirm('You have Checked only few locations among the List. \n Are you sure, you do not want to Prescribe from the other locations? ');
                            } else if (cboxes == 0) {
                                alert('Please select atleast One Address \n Where you would prefer to prescribe from.');
                                return false;
                            }
                            else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
</script>
```

please advise how can i get this done?

Comment: What is your code so far? Post relevant parts and we'll see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using [standard plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate), such code should be supported:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({ 
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            SomeFuncHere();
        }
    });
})
```

The code in `submitHandler` should be called after successful validation.

Edit: based on your code, try this instead:

```
$("#myform").validate({ 
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var cboxes = ($('input:checkbox:checked').filter(":checked").length);
        var nboxes = ($(":checkbox:not(:checked)").length);
        var flag = false;
        if ((cboxes > 0) && (nboxes > 0)) {
            flag = confirm('You have Checked only few locations among the List. \n Are you sure, you do not want to Prescribe from the other locations? ');
        } else if (cboxes == 0) {
            alert('Please select atleast One Address \n Where you would prefer to prescribe from.');
        }
        else {
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }
});
```

Comment: I could pick your suggestions, so I have pasted my script hopw you can help me better

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the jQuery validate plugin then the [valid()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method returns a boolean to indicate whether or not the form validated successfully, so you could just do:

```
if ($("#myform").valid()) {
    CallSomeOtherFunction();
}
```

Comment: I could pick your suggestions, so I have pasted my script hopw you can help me better

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `.validate().form()`

```
if (!$("#myform").validate().form()) {
    return false; //doesn't validate
}else
{
    //form is validated do your work
}
```