# submitting form jquery validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation plugin to validate contact form in my web but I don't know how to pass form fields after validation to a php file to send it to  my peronal email.

This is my js code:

```
 $('#contact-us').validate(
 {
  rules: {
    contactName: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    subject: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    },
    comments: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }

    });
}); // end document.ready
```

I think I have to use something like [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527757/how-to-submit-and-validate-a-form-via-ajax) but I can't get it work.

Anybody could help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to rely on AJAX to submit the form, or the default browser action to do so? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I'm not sure about that @Terry which is simple way? I only want validate and send it if every field is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the php form in the action section of the form whose script will run once a form is validated.

Sample contact form html code

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" id="formwa">
<label  for="name">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name here">
<label  for="email">Email address</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Keep me Updated!</button>
</form>
```

Correspondin submit.php code

```
<?php
  //$to = $_POST['to'] ;    
  $message = "Hi there, \n You have a new visitor on your Website.\n\r The person's name is: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n\r\nAnd the person's Email id is: ".$_POST['email'];
  $from = $_POST['email'];
  $headers =  "From: ".$_POST['email'];
  mail( "you@yourdomain.com", "Subject Line for the Email", $message, $headers);
  // mail( "another@yourdomain.com", "Carbon Copy: Subject Line", $message, $headers);

?>
```

I hope that'll help you to understand it. The above codes lack validation, but alright, you have been working on validation itself. Ask more in case of more confusion.
Cheers

Comment: Oh my god! what stupid I am xD as easy like that!! I supossed I had to do it with jquery too!!

Comment: jquery is a set of javascript libraries, made to do our javascripting easier. in this case, all they accomplish is validating. However, submitting forms via ajax is another option, but little complex

Answer (score -2):

```
< form action="email.php" >
```

In the form action page you can get the values there you can send the email

Comment: describe what you'd do there, otherwise this isn't very useful information for the OP...